# How do I print an error in python?

Tags: python

I have recently just finished up some code of a very basic troubleshooting system. I'm just trying to add some validation so that if the user inputs anything which isn't yes or no on any of the questions then it will print 'Invalid input' in the shell but just not sure how to do it exactly. Can someone help me, please? Much appreciated.

My code:

```
prompt = "> "

print ("screen question one here")
screen = input(prompt)
if screen == "yes":
    print ("screen question two here")
    screen2 = input(prompt)
    if screen2 == "yes":
        print ("screen question three here")
        screen3 = input(prompt)
        if screen3 == "yes":
            print ("screen advice one here")
        elif screen3 == "no":
            print ("screen adivce two here")
    elif screen2 == "no":
        print ("camera question one here")
        camera = input(prompt)
        if camera == "yes":
            print ("camera question two here")
            camera2 = input(prompt)
            if camera2 == "yes":
                print ("camera advice one here")
            elif camera2 == "no":
                print ("camera advice two here")
        elif camera == "no":
            print ("water question one here")
            water = input(prompt)
            if water == "yes":
                print ("water question two here")
                water2 = input(prompt)
                if water2 == "yes":
                    print ("water advice one here")
                elif water2 == "no":
                    print ("water advice two here")
            elif water == "no":
                print ("buttons question one here")
                buttons = input(prompt)
                if buttons == "yes":
                    print ("buttons advice one here")
                elif buttons == "no":
                    print ("buttons advice two here")  
elif screen == "no":
    print ("battery question one here")
    battery = input(prompt)
    if battery == "yes":
        print ("battery question two here")
        battery2 = input(prompt)
        if battery2 == "yes":
            print ("battery advice one here")
        elif battery2 == "no":
            print ("battery advice two here")
    elif battery == "no":
        print ("wifi question one here")
        wifi = input(prompt)
        if wifi == "yes":
            print ("wifi advice one here")
        elif wifi == "no":
            print ("wifi advice two here")
```

Comment: First, write a function that gets a yes or no from the user. Focus on getting that working as you want, and then after that you can use it for all your different questions.

Comment: use `else`! But I guess you alredy knew.

Comment: Still struggling, it's either working for some questions or not at all. Can you help please? @khelwood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you might do it.

Define a function that gets a yes or no from the user. What people tend to want is to repeat the question until the user gives you a suitable response: that is what this function does.

```
def yesorno(question):
    while True:
        print(question)
        answer = input('> ').strip().lower()
        if answer in ('y', 'yes'):
            return True
        if answer in ('n', 'no'):
            return False
        print("Invalid input")
```

On the other hand, if you just want to exit your script when you get invalid input, you could do this:

```
def yesorno(question):
    print(question)
    answer = input('> ').strip().lower()
    if answer in ('y', 'yes'):
        return True
    if answer in ('n', 'no'):
        return False
    exit('Invalid input')
```

`exit` will simply exit your whole program. It's not necessarily what I would recommend.

Either way, you can use `yesorno` like this:

```
if yesorno("Question 1"):
    # User answered yes
    if yesorno("Question 2A"):
        # User answered yes
    else:
        # User answered no
else:
    # User answered no
    if yesorno("Question 2B"):
        ...
```

Comment: This works perfectly! May I ask, what does .strip() does in this code? Thank you. @khelwood

Comment: [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) removes surrounding spaces from a string, so if the user types `"  yes"` it will be converted to `"yes"`.